# Extend message trace period in Exchange office365 to 90 days via power shell cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, office365, powershell-3.0

Default time limit of get-messagetrace is 30 days. i want to extend that to 90 days via powershell.how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Get-MessageTrace is limited to 7 days. Start-HistoricalSearch will allow you to search the full 90 days.

Refer to [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200741%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#CanIrunamessagetraceviaremoteWindowsPowerShell) about more detail about message trace.